# Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting (match operator)

Tags: angularjs, haml

I keep getting the following error:

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations:
>
> [[{"msg":"person.kind.match('customer')","newVal":["customer"],"oldVal":["customer"]}],[{"msg":"person.kind.match('customer')","newVal":["customer"],"oldVal":"<>"}],[{"msg":"person.kind.match('customer')","newVal":["customer"],"oldVal":"<>"}],[{"msg":"person.kind.match('customer')","newVal":["customer"],"oldVal":"<>"}],[{"msg":"person.kind.match('customer')","newVal":["customer"],"oldVal":"<>"}]]

The code which is causing this issue is below:

```
%p{ng: {if: "person.kind.match('partner')" } } Some text
.btn{ ng: { if: "person.kind.match('customer')" } } Some other text
  //more button here
```

I have looked at existing questions and all of them are different. My issue is caused by the match operator. How can I use the test operator here.

**Note**: I am not changing objects/models during the render of the view. I am just using the match operator

Comment: pls post your `match` function

Comment: its already there in the view code `.btn{ ng: { if: "person.kind.match('customer')" } } Some other text
`

Comment: This means the result of firing a watch is returning a new value on subsequent calls (the function being bound to is not idempotent most likely)

Comment: My error is because of the match operator. AFAIK, it does not mutate the scope

Comment: thanks @zooly, it does make the understanding of this issue a bit clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears that the match operator was mutating the `person.kind` causing the `10 $digest() iterations reached` error. I changed my implementation to use `includes` function instead of `match` operator to fix the issue.

Comment: Alternative: Use `!!person.kind.match`